# set up 2 accounts

Tags: truffle, ganache-cli

I am trying to implement a KYC system for banks. so for this, I will require the banks to have a respective account address so when the customer joins that bank he will pay to it. I have provided the sample code here. can someone help with how I can add the address to this?

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;
contract kyc {
    // Model a bank
    struct BankName {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint customercount;
        address payable acc;
    }
    // average price to bank
    uint public KYC_PRICE = 1 ether;
    // Store accounts that have joined
    mapping(address => bool) public customers;
    // Read/write Banks into the system
    mapping(uint => BankName) public bankname;
    // Store number of banks Count
    uint public bankCount;

    // joined event
    event joinEvent (
        uint indexed _BankId
    );

    constructor() public {
        addBank("Bank A");
        addBank("Bank B");
    }

    // ...
    function addBank(string memory _name,address payable acc) private {
        bankCount ++;
        bankname[bankCount] = BankName(bankCount, _name, 0);
    }

    function join (uint _BankId) public {

        // require a valid bank 
        require(_BankId > 0 && _BankId <= bankCount);
        // record that customer has joined
        customers[msg.sender] = true;
        // update Bank customer count
        bankname[_BankId].customercount ++;
        // trigger voted event
        emit joinEvent(_BankId);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass parameters to the constructor.

Comment: ok, I can pass the parameters to the constructor. But is it ok if I deploy twice in migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js because I need the same parameters for bank A and bank B??

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @Ismael I got the solution.
I changed my constructor as this:

```
constructor(address payable _acc1,address payable _acc2) public {
        addBank("Bank A", _acc1);
        addBank("Bank B", _acc2);
    }
```

and in migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js as this:

```
var kyc = artifacts.require("./kyc.sol");

var accounts=web3.eth.getAccounts();
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    const acc1=accounts[0];
    const acc2=accounts[1];
  deployer.deploy(kyc,acc1,acc2);
};
```